# Add extra condition to jointable in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, join, where-clause

I have 2 tables which are related using a mapping table i.e FK of these tables are stored in a mapping table (Joining table).

Users {
uid,
uname
}

Dept {
deptid,
dept_name
}

User_Dept{
ud_id,
uid
deptid
status
}

So in my User Entity i have ManytoOne relation with Dept Entity and have added @Jointable annotation to joining table ( User_Dept) like below
User.java

`````
````@ManyToOne
    ````@JoinTable(
      ````name="UserDept",
      ````joinColumns = ````{@JoinColumn(name="uid",referencedColumnName="uid")},
    ````  inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="deptid", ````referencedColumnName="deptid")}
    ````)
    ````private Dept dept;
}

All good!!

But i have a business scenario to fetch only those users belonging to a particular Dept and who are 'active'.

Basically i need to add extra condition to my @jointable(user_dept) to fetch those users whose "status=active" from user_dept table.
I have tried adding @WhereJoinTable(clause = "status=active") like below
class User { 

````@JoinTable(
    ````  name="UserDept",
      ````joinColumns = ````{@JoinColumn(name="uid",referencedColumnName="uid")},
    ````  inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="deptid", ````referencedColumnName="deptid")}
````)
````@WhereJoinTable(clause = "status=active")
````}

And also @where(clause = "status=active") at class level.Nothing works.
Issue:
1. where annotation adds a condition to the base query on User table instead of user_dept table.
2. wherejointable annotation- doesnt seem to have any impact.
3. Tried adding @where on userdept class (based on point 1) , but no luck.
Can someone help? 
Also if you can propose any alternate solution even thatworks
`````

Comment: You cannot have differnet conditions in on a OneToMany mapping. IMO this is also not necessary because you only want to fetch particular data so it's a projection that you should do with a query and use DTOs

Comment: hmm.. some snippet or sample ref would be helpful @SimonMartinelli

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/